# How do I run a selenium test case using Jenkins, on a mac?

Tags: java, shell, selenium, jenkins

Following this tutorial :https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/integration-of-jenkins-with-selenium-webdriver/

Its windows based and I am using a mac.
I have my test case written in java.
It works fine when run using eclipse but I want to configure a build on jenkins to run it.
Can someone help me?
The steps in the lesson don't work for me.

I have tried creating a shell file to run it but I am a bit unsure on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it using Maven!

Just follow this tutorial as there is no point in me repeating these steps.

https://www.guru99.com/maven-jenkins-with-selenium-complete-tutorial.html
Thanks